# Ruby syntax, semantic questions def status=(status)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was looking at this code and was trying to figure what `def status=(status)` means. I have never seen that before.

```
class Tweet
attr_accessor :status

def initialize(options={})
self.status = options[:status]
end

def public?
self.status && self.status[0] != "@"
end

def status=(status)
@status = status ? status[0...140] : status
end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

That is a setter - the method to be called when you say `thing.status = whatever`.

Without such a method, saying `thing.status = whatever` would be illegal, since that syntax is merely syntactic sugar for calling the setter.

Comment: It's worth noting that `attr_accessor :status` creates both `status()` and `status=(value)` methods, but it's being overwritten here by the explicit definition.

Comment: Yes, I was going to go on to suggest that perhaps the reason the OP has never seen this syntax is that he is accustomed to seeing / using `attr_accessor` instead. The point being that `attr_accessor` creates, as you say, both the getter and setter methods - so that many ruby users go their whole lives without seeing an *explicit* getter or setter method!

Answer (score 4):

I'll try answering this in layman's terms, since I didn't understand this when starting out.

Let's say you want the `Tweet` class to have an attribute `status`. Now you want to change that attribute, well you can't since it's hidden inside the class. The only way you can interact with *anything* inside a class is by creating a method to do so:

```
def status=(status)
  @status = status # using @ makes @status a class instance variable, so you can interact with this attribute in other methods inside this class
end
```

Great! Now I can do this:

```
tweet = Tweet.new
tweet.status = "200" # great this works
# now lets get the status back:
tweet.status # blows up!
```

We can't access the `status` variable since we haven't defined a method that does that.

```
def status
  @status # returns whatever @status is, will return nil if not set
end
```

Now `tweet.status` will work as well.

There are shorthands for this:

```
attr_setter :status #like the first method
attr_reader :status # like the second one
attr_accessor :status # does both of the above
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly the same thing that `def foo` *always* means: define a method named `foo`.

```
def initialize
```

Defines a method named `initialize`.

```
def public?
```

Defines a method named `public?`

```
def status=
```

Defines a method named `status=`

That's it. There's absolutely nothing special going on here. There is no magic when defining a method whose name ends in an `=` sign.

The magic happens when *calling* a method whose name ends in an `=` sign. Basically, you are allowed to insert whitespace in between the `=` sign and the rest of the method name. So, instead of having to call the method like this

```
foo.status= 42
```

You can call it like this:

```
foo.status = 42
```

Which makes it look like an assignment. Note: it is also treated like an assignment in another way; just like with all other forms of assignments, assignment expressions evaluate to the value that is being assigned, which means that the return value of the method is *ignored* in this case.